# bash: Split log into parsable chunks

Tags: bash, subversion

I have a variable `log` which contains svn history:

```
$ log=$(svn log -r 9:11)
$ echo "%s\n" "$log"
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9 | stew | 2021-03-06 20:14:57 +0100 (Sat, 06 Mar 2021) | 1 line

Moving things to trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r10 | stew | 2021-03-06 20:16:27 +0100 (Sat, 06 Mar 2021) | 1 line

Adding script svn2redmine
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r11 | stew | 2021-03-06 20:19:38 +0100 (Sat, 06 Mar 2021) | 2 lines

Moving stuff to a file execute permissions.
This is a multi-line message
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a good script which will parse individual commit messages.  But right now I call it with:

```
for rev in {9..11}; do
  parse "$(svn log -r $rev)"
done
```

That means, I'm making lots of `svn log` requests which each establishes another connection to the server and is thus slow.  I'd rather:

```
log=$(svn log -r 9:11)
for commit in "$log"; do
  parse "$commit"
done
```

But how can I split `"$log"` into individual commits?

Comment: I assume the `echo "%s\n" "$log"` should be `printf "%s\n" "$log"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert `"$log"` into an array containing the commits.  The splitting needs to be done based on a multi-character string so `IFS=` isn't going to help here.

```
log=$(svn log -r 9:11)

... Something here to split "$log" into an array of commits ...

for commit in "${commits[@]}"; do
  parse "$commit"
done
```

That splitting is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789518/1723954) and can look like this:

```
delimiter='------------------------------------------------------------------------'
export -a commits
while [ "$log" != "${log#*$delimiter}" ]; do
   part="${log%%$delimiter*}"
   part="${part##$'\n'}"
   commits+=("${part%%$'\n'}")
   log="${log#*$delimiter}"
done
```

Where:

- `"${log#*$delimiter}"` removes everything up to (and including) the first delimiter
- `"${log%%$delimiter*}"` extracts everything up to (but excluding) the next delimiter
- `"${part##$'\n'}"` removes the leading `\n` which was at  the end of the delimiter
- `"${part%%$'\n'}"` removes the trailing `\n` which was at the end of the message